# NotNull condition is not working for withColumn condition in spark data frame scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-xml

So I am trying to add column when I find it but I so not want to add when column is not present in the xml schema .
This is what I am doing I guess I am doing something wrong in checking the condition .

```
  val temp = tempNew1
  .withColumn("BookMark", when($"AsReportedItem.fs:BookMark".isNotNull or $"AsReportedItem.fs:BookMark" =!= "", 0))
  .withColumn("DocByteOffset", when($"AsReportedItem.fs:DocByteOffset".isNotNull or $"AsReportedItem.fs:DocByteOffset" =!= "", 0))
  .withColumn("DocByteLength", when($"AsReportedItem.fs:DocByteLength".isNotNull or $"AsReportedItem.fs:DocByteLength" =!= "", 0))
  .withColumn("EditedDescription", when($"AsReportedItem.fs:EditedDescription".isNotNull or $"AsReportedItem.fs:EditedDescription" =!= "", 0))
  .withColumn("EditedDescription", when($"AsReportedItem.fs:EditedDescription._VALUE".isNotNull or $"AsReportedItem.fs:EditedDescription._VALUE" =!= "", 0))
  .withColumn("EditedDescription_languageId", when($"AsReportedItem.fs:EditedDescription._languageId".isNotNull or $"AsReportedItem.fs:EditedDescription._languageId" =!= "", 0))
  .withColumn("ReportedDescription", when($"AsReportedItem.fs:ReportedDescription._VALUE".isNotNull or $"AsReportedItem.fs:ReportedDescription._VALUE" =!= "", 0))
  .withColumn("ReportedDescription_languageId", when($"AsReportedItem.fs:ReportedDescription._languageId".isNotNull or $"AsReportedItem.fs:ReportedDescription._languageId" =!= "", 0))
  .withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName_languageId", when($"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._languageId".isNotNull or $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._languageId" =!= "", 0))
  .withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName", when($"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._VALUE".isNotNull or $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._VALUE" =!= "", 0))
  .withColumn("PeriodPermId_objectTypeId", when($"PeriodPermId._objectTypeId".isNotNull or $"PeriodPermId._objectTypeId" =!= "", 0))
  .withColumn("PeriodPermId", when($"PeriodPermId._VALUE".isNotNull or $"PeriodPermId._VALUE" =!= "", 0))
  .drop($"AsReportedItem").drop($"AsReportedItem")
```

But when I find column it works fine for me but when column is not present in `tempNew1`  I get error .

**Basically I don't want to do withColumn at all if tag is not found in the schema .**

Soothing I am missing here .Please help me identify the issue .

The error I get is below

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   cannot resolve '`AsReportedItem.fs:BookMark`' given input columns:
>   [IsAsReportedCurrencySetManually,

This is also i have tried

```
    def hasColumn(df: DataFrame, path: String) = Try(df(path)).isSuccess
 val temp = tempNew1.withColumn("BookMark", when(hasColumn(tempNew1,"AsReportedItem.fs:BookMark") == true, $"AsReportedItem.fs:BookMark"))
```

But not able to make it work fully ..

This is working but how can I write it for all columns .

```
val temp = if (hasColumn(tempNew1, "AsReportedItem")) {
      tempNew1
        .withColumn("BookMark", $"AsReportedItem.fs:BookMark")
        .withColumn("DocByteOffset", $"AsReportedItem.fs:DocByteOffset")
        .withColumn("DocByteLength", $"AsReportedItem.fs:DocByteLength")
        .withColumn("EditedDescription", $"AsReportedItem.fs:EditedDescription")
        .withColumn("EditedDescription", $"AsReportedItem.fs:EditedDescription._VALUE")
        .withColumn("EditedDescription_languageId", $"AsReportedItem.fs:EditedDescription._languageId")
        .withColumn("ReportedDescription", $"AsReportedItem.fs:ReportedDescription._VALUE")
        .withColumn("ReportedDescription_languageId", $"AsReportedItem.fs:ReportedDescription._languageId")
        .withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName_languageId", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._languageId")
        .withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._VALUE")
        .withColumn("PeriodPermId_objectTypeId", $"PeriodPermId._objectTypeId")
        .withColumn("PeriodPermId", $"PeriodPermId._VALUE")
        .drop($"AsReportedItem")
    } else {
      tempNew1
        .withColumn("BookMark", lit(null))
        .withColumn("DocByteOffset", lit(null))
        .withColumn("DocByteLength", lit(null))
        .withColumn("EditedDescription", lit(null))
        .withColumn("EditedDescription", lit(null))
        .withColumn("EditedDescription_languageId", lit(null))
        .withColumn("ReportedDescription", lit(null))
        .withColumn("ReportedDescription_languageId", lit(null))
        .withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName_languageId", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._languageId")
        .withColumn("FinancialAsReportedLineItemName", $"FinancialAsReportedLineItemName._VALUE")
        .withColumn("PeriodPermId_objectTypeId", $"PeriodPermId._objectTypeId")
        .withColumn("PeriodPermId", $"PeriodPermId._VALUE")
        .drop($"AsReportedItem")

    }
```

Adding schema of the main data frame

```
root
 |-- DataPartition: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TimeStamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- SourceId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialStatementLineItem_lineItemId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialStatementLineItem_lineItemInstanceKey: long (nullable = true)
 |-- StatementCurrencyId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- StatementTypeCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- uniqueFundamentalSet: long (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EstimateMethodCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EstimateMethodId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialAsReportedLineItemName: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _languageId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialStatementLineItemSequence: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialStatementLineItemValue: double (nullable = true)
 |-- FiscalYear: long (nullable = true)
 |-- IsAnnual: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsAsReportedCurrencySetManually: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsCombinedItem: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsDerived: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsExcludedFromStandardization: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsFinal: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsTotal: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodEndDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PeriodPermId: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _objectTypeId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ReportedCurrencyId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- StatementSectionCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- StatementSectionId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- StatementSectionIsCredit: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- SystemDerivedTypeCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SystemDerivedTypeCodeId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Unit: double (nullable = true)
 |-- UnitEnumerationId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FFAction|!|: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PartitionYear: long (nullable = true)
 |-- PartitionStatement: string (nullable = true)
```

Adding schema after columns appears in the schema

```
|-- uniqueFundamentalSet: long (nullable = true)
 |-- AsReportedItem: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fs:BookMark: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fs:DocByteLength: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fs:DocByteOffset: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fs:EditedDescription: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _languageId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fs:ItemDisplayedNegativeFlag: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fs:ItemDisplayedValue: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fs:ItemScalingFactor: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fs:ReportedDescription: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _languageId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fs:ReportedValue: double (nullable = true)
 |-- EstimateMethodCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EstimateMethodId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialAsReportedLineItemName: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _languageId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialLineItemSource: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: You can check the `columns` property of the `tempNew1` dataset for the existence of the `AsReportedItem.fs:BookMark` column, and call the `withColumn` conditionally based on the result. See (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904136/how-do-i-detect-if-a-spark-dataframe-has-a-column) for more details

Comment: @AlexSavitsky but I have 10 such columns do I have to do it one by one ?

Comment: Yes. You can, however, put your columns in a `Seq`, filter it against the dataset columns, and then fold your dataset using `withColumn`, to make it somewhat functional-style

Comment: @AlexSavitsky I just tried with hasColumn but something is missing ..Can please look at the syntax if you can spare some time ..

Comment: As @AlexSavitsky has pointed you to use foldleft, use the idea but the codes presented will not work. You will have to use his idea to play with struct columns that you have and you shall get it solved ;)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes it does not work as it is ..I am trying that out...

Comment: @RameshMaharjan cant we do something in simpler way like with hasColumn ?

Comment: you could have done it in simple ways if your table didn't have struct types. but your columns are mostly structs isn't it?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes ...

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have updated my code which is actually working but its a very dumb way to make it work,but easy for me to understand ..

Comment: firstly I am not understanding your requirement that you want to populate 0 for not null value or populate with whatever is the value in that struct element? what is your requirement? and secondly do you want to create all those new columns even though you don't have those elements in original struct field? can you clarify those two points

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169640/discussion-between-atharv-thakur-and-ramesh-maharjan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to show you general way to apply the logic on *AsReportedItem struct column* ( I have commented in the code for clarity)

```
//required column names even though the elements are not present in AsReportedItem struct column
val requiredAsReportedItemColumns = Array("BookMark", "DocByteOffset", "DocByteLength", "EditedDescription", "EditedDescription", "EditedDescription_languageId", "ReportedDescription", "ReportedDescription_languageId")
//selecting the elements of AsReportedItem struct columns for checking condition using when
//checking for structfields inside the selected struct field
def getFields(parent: String, schema: StructType): Seq[String] = schema.fields.flatMap {
  case StructField(name, t: StructType, _, _) => getFields(parent + name + ".", t)
  case StructField(name, _, _, _) => Seq(s"$parent$name")
}

//checking for struct column if present the get the fields of nested structs as well
val AsReportedItemColumns = if(tempNew1.columns.contains("AsReportedItem")) getFields("", tempNew1.select("AsReportedItem.*").schema).toArray.map(x => x.substring(3, x.length)) else Array.empty[String]

//finding difference between required number of columns and the elements present in AsReportedItem struct column
val notInAsReportedItemColumns = requiredAsReportedItemColumns.diff(AsReportedItemColumns.map(x => x.toString.replace(".", "")))

//checking condition for the elements present in AsReportedItem struct column
val temp_for_AsReportedItem = AsReportedItemColumns.foldLeft(tempNew1){(tempdf, name) => tempdf.withColumn(name.replace(".", ""), col(s"AsReportedItem.fs:$name"))}
//populating nulls for the columns that are not present in AsReportedItem struct column
val final_AsReportedItem = notInAsReportedItemColumns.foldLeft(temp_for_AsReportedItem){(tempdf, name)=> tempdf.withColumn(name, lit(null))}.drop("AsReportedItem")
```

Apply the same logic for the rest of two struct columns `FinancialAsReportedLineItemName` and `PeriodPermId` but on the transformed datframe i.e. **on `final_AsReportedItem`** and **not on `tempNew1`**

**Credit to** https://stackoverflow.com/a/47104148/5880706

Comment: Getting error `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'AsReportedItem.*' give input columns 'PartitionYear, EstimateMethodId, EstimateMethodCode`

Comment: I have added that in the question

Comment: Ok so this is not throwing any error ..But I need to explode after getting the columns ..

Comment: I am searching for an example sorry for delay

Comment: So this the issue ...`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`AsReportedItem`.`fs:EditedDescription` = '')' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(`AsReportedItem`.`fs:EditedDescription` = '')' (struct<_VALUE:string,_languageId:bigint> and string).;;` because when columns appears the type is different

Comment: Yes I tried removing that earlier but still getting error ..`No such struct field BookMark in fs:BookMark, fs:DocByteLength`

Comment: But this code will not work for `EditedDescription` which is again struct type inside AsReportedItem..I mean I will get that as an array so do I have to explode that ? ..This is what I was taking about earlier and was searching for to generate this scenario

Comment: you should look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103823/how-can-i-explode-a-struct-in-a-dataframe-without-hard-coding-the-column-names

Comment: sorry for the frequent question ..I am going to try this out ..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Putting it as an answer, as it's getting too big for comments.

Assuming you have a collection of the columns you'd like to add:

```
val cols = Seq("BookMark")
```

you would need to repeatedly call `withColumn` on your original `DataFrame`, assigning the result to a new `DataFrame`. There's a functional operation that does just that, called `fold`:

```
val result = cols.foldLeft(tempNew1)((df, name) =>
  df.withColumn(name, if (df.column.contains(s"AsReportedItem.fs:$name"))
    col(s"AsReportedItem.fs:$name") else lit("null")))
```

`fold` takes the first argument (`tempNew1` in your case) and calls the provided function for each element in `cols`, assigning the result to a new `DataFrame` each time

Comment: I am not getting error but for all record I am getting null value inly